# TextField In a TabBar in a .sheet() break presentation detents in ios17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17

i would like to show a UIPageView-like content inside a `sheet` with `.medium` or custom `presentationDetent` size. It seems to work for ios16 but not ios17.

For this i embed a `TabView` with `PageTabViewStyle` style in the sheet.

It works correctly (beside issues with ignoring the safeArea), but it appear that if i embed a TextField inside it, independently of which nesting level, it will break the detent. **The sheet will show full screen (instead of medium) and weird layout behaviours may happen.**

Here is some minimal code to reproduce it:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text = "text"
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("SHOW SHEET") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            TabView {
                TextField("Venue name", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                TextField("Venue name", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing the Textfield with `Color.green` or any other view works correctly.

### Testing

Built with xcode 15.0

- Issue reproducible on ios17 simulator and real device
- Works correctly on ios16 simulator and real device.

Comment: removing the `tabViewStyle` made it present half sheet style

Comment: Yes indeed @TejaNandamuri but sadly i need it. I think it is a conflict between sheet, tab and keyboard, cos the same i can reproduce also with `TextEditor` and alike.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri, having a List with a TextField or a Picker in the sheet breaks the presentation as well :-(